# Does Symfony or Twig have something similar as Laravel's "view composer"?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, twig, templating

I would like to know if Symfony has a service for similar function as Laravel's "view composer"? Does Twig support that feature? Are there any bundles that support it?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I solved the problem by creating a new service that provided appropriate data and then using [Service Container Parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services) to integrate the service in Twig.

Answer (score 1):

Twig uses :

- [Filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters)
- [Functions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions)

You can create a custom filter or a custom function to do something similar as Laravel's "view composer".